# Streaming data to two files per day using file() in R

Tags: r, api, file, twitter

Solution: the code below works when you wrap format(Sys.time(), "%H") in as.numeric.

I have a constant stream of data coming in from Twitter's Streaming API using R. I am using code from streamR, which is a package to handle streaming API data from Twitter. I would like the data coming in to go to two different files per day. With the code below, I attempted to stream data into two different files each day (one after 12PM and one before 12PM), but it does not seem to be working. Below is the code necessary for streaming, which is part of the larger function filterStream in streamR (the code for the whole function is available upon request; I realize that this is not easily reproducible without an API app.)

```
conn <- file(description = "after12.json")
conn2 <- file(description = "before12.json")

    write.tweets <- function(x) {
      if (nchar(x) > 0 && format(Sys.time(), "%H") >= 12){
        open(conn, open="a")
        writeLines(x, conn, sep = "")
      } else if (nchar(x) > 0) {
        open(conn2, open="a")
        writeLines(x, conn2, sep = "")
      } 
    }

    if (!is.null(oauth)){
        url <- "https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json"
        output <- tryCatch(oauth$OAuthRequest(URL=url, params=params, method="POST", 
            customHeader=NULL, timeout = timeout, writefunction = write.tweets, 
            cainfo=system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")), 
                error=function(e) e)
        close(conn)
    }
```

The stream seems to go into one file only, and does not switch at 12. The problem seems to be that the write function channels the data into the file that is appropriate when the stream *started* rather than switching mid-stream. For example, if I started the stream at 11AM, the "before12.json" file would be populated, but "after12.json" would not begin to populated at 12.

Is this the right way to go? I would rather not stop the API stream and start it up again. I lose data, and the API can be testy with repeated connections.

Please let me know any solutions, or general directions I may be missing! Thanks!

Edit 1: I'd like to say that the write.tweets function actually works when you try it on its own. If you tell it to write text, it will switch times on schedule. However, the streaming data does not seem to want to switch between.

Comment: That doesn't explain everything but `format(Sys.time(), "%H")` should be wrapped in `as.numeric`. Or it might be the only bug if you were not totally honest with your *For example* section.

Comment: @flodel, why the need to wrap? This gives TRUE for me: `"13">12`.

Comment: Because R will convert 12 to "12" and compare strings. See the difference between `as.character(0:23) > 12` and `0:23 > 12`.

Comment: @flodel, so simple... Thanks for your patience! I'm afraid I've used this kind of comparison somewhere... :-0

Comment: @flodel, have you tried format(Sys.time(), "%H") >= 12 in R? It works fine for me. I just tried it for 8PM and it changed on schedule.

Comment: `format(Sys.time(), "%H")` will return a string: from `"0"` to `"23"`. All possible values are `as.character(0:23)`. Now see for yourself that `as.character(0:23) >= 12` is not what you are looking for. It might match your expectations (`0:23 >= 12`) for some hours of the data, but not all. Hence the need to fix that part of your code by using `as.numeric` as I suggested.